# How can I recover files after accidentally running "git clean -df"?

Tags: git, data-recovery, git-clean

I have accidentally run `git clean -df`. It removed my files from my current commit, which I had yet to push. Now, in `git status`, those files are marked with `D`, which means "deleted".

Is there any way to get those files back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clean` only untracked files and not committed ones.

You might have done other operations if you see `D` as the status for already committed files.

You get back those files, do:

```
git checkout .
```

or

```
git reset --hard
```