# Accidentally deleted all of my file using git clean

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I accidentally deleted almost all of my file by executing `git clean -df` command in terminal. Is there any way to undo this action? Now all my files in my computer is gone.
Thank you.

Comment: Solution is reported here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722470/how-can-i-recover-files-after-accidentally-running-git-clean-df

Comment: "all my files in my computer", can you clarify what you mean by that? Did you put a repository on the root of your system disk or something like that? Note that `git clean` will, when given the right options, remove files that aren't tracked and unless you have a separate backup of them, then *no*, there is no way to ask *git* to restore those files.

Comment: @ES2018 That is not a very good answer for this question as the conclusion there is that something else must've been done as well, since `git clean` only removes *untracked* files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+clean

Answer (score 1):

sadly, the short answer id no.

Unless you added file or committed them once, git has no mean to know about them; that is exactly what you meant with your git clean (from `man git clean`):

> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that **are not**
>   under version control

thus git cannot help you here...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone facing same issue and using any modern IDEs (like PHP storm or Intelli j etc.), these IDEs store local files in their change history.

I used `git clean -f -d` and one of my untracked files was removed from code base, however I was able to recover it by:

Going to `View menu` of PHP storm and clicking `recent changes`.

I am sure other IDEs would have same change history log somewhere just google it.

Answer (score 0):

In general every action done on git is logged in `git reflog`.
Then you see the git hashtags of each action done on git.
So, you can write that command and then do `git reset --hard`
to the hashtag of the command before you did `git clean`. So for example if you did `git commit ...` (and git hashtag is #exampl) before `git clean ...`, you write in your terminal: `git reset --hard #exampl` and you're back to the state you were before you did your unwanted command.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't hold true for `git clean`, as `git clean` removes files that *aren't* tracked.